# How to encode Scala case class with more than 22 fields to JSON using Argonaut?

Tags: json, scala, encoding, argonaut

I have a case class that has more than 22 fields in it. Let's say it looks like this (Scala pseudo code):

```
case class X(A1: Int, A2: Int, ..., A22: Int, A23: Int, ..., A40: Int)
```

Currently I can see only `jencode` function up to 22 fields so `jencode22L` is the max. In addition to encoding this to JSON I would like to manually map the field names to something else. For example I would `A1` to become, let's say, `a1` and `A2` let's say `b2`.

How do you do this in Argonaut?

Comment: Would be curious your specific constraints on versions because these limits have been removed in core libs but perhaps not argonaut although I see support for the latest versions (2.12).  These questions always are controversial because people will say your design is off if your class requires that many fields. To be fair though in enterprise development I have had to maintain classes like this with PlayJson and I think the best route is to start using composition inside the class to stay in the limit. I once extended it myself but for readability I think the composition route is easier.

Comment: I think your best bet is https://github.com/alexarchambault/argonaut-shapeless to use macro based encoder derivation which should bypass this limit.

Comment: Solved with a custom encoding code. That was the easiest way. Anyway, that's true. I've grouped the fields and wrote subgroups encoders.